# linux - shutdown from mate only logs out (back to display manager)

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint, shutdown, desktop

I am using Linux Mint Debian Edition 2 with MATE desktop, and I upgraded it to Debian testing repository.

When I press Shutdown or Restart from within MATE desktop, it only logs out, and goes back to MDM (mate display manager) login screen

I tried replacing `mdm` with `slim`, but that did not make any difference.

I checked `/var/log/messages` but there was no errors or any particular log at that time. Only something like this:

```
Oct 13 19:27:16 saeedgnu-lenovo ag[3076]: mdm-superinit Starting...
Oct 13 19:27:16 saeedgnu-lenovo ag[3077]: mdm-superinit Finished
```

I also added `acpi=force` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` and ran `update-grub`, still no difference.

My machine is a Lenovo Flex 2 laptop (core i7)

My kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux saeedgnu-lenovo 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt7-1 (2015-03-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux11
```

Is there anything else I can check?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the user shutting down sudo-capable?

Comment: @FrankThomas yes, it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by running this command

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/polkit-mate
```

I copy my home directory after each Linux installation, even though my old system was Linux Mint too, I think the command for policykit was changed after upgrading the system (from `/usr/lib/polkit-mate/polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1`). So the policykit deamon was not starting after login.